# Запрет на дублирование записей в базе даных

Tags: delphi, база-данных, ado, ms-access

Имеется небольшое учебное (для курсовой) приложение на Delphi для работы с базой данных, обладает базовой функциональностью. Ее необходимо расширить, добавив условие, которое будет запрещать юзеру добавлять в базу данных такие записи, которые в ней уже есть, то бишь дублировать данные.

Добавление осуществляется с помощью специальных делфячных комбобоксов и эдитов для базы данных, просто потому что так было проще.

Вопрос: Какой самый неинвазивный способ проверять данные на дублирование в БД?

1. Отлавливать ошибки, возвращаемые сервером при добавлении и обрабатывать исключение?
2. Составить хитрый SQL запрос (какой?), результаты которого можно будет использовать в условии?
3. ???

База данных в Access, механизм обращения к базе - ADO. Стоит учесть, что возможно в 2007 Delphi обрезанный язык запросов и некоторые хитрые SQL запросы могут не срабатывать.

Answer (score 2):

Это стандартный механизм баз данных - уникальный индекс. Формируете такой индекс, и база будет вам швырять исключение при попытке устроить дубликат.

Другие способы - это дикие костыли и употребляться они не должны.

Comment: К своему стыду в первый раз слышу об уникальных индексах, все оказалось гораздо проще чем я думал.